# Managing NPM packages via a script

Tags: node.js

Is there a library or is it perhaps built into NPM itself to manage packages and install them within a script? I'm writing a process that checks if a local package exists and installs if it doesn't. Then I'd like to be able to dynamically require it in the same process.

Comment: Could wrap your node launch with supervisord or similar then have node update its own packages.json  then terminate to trigger a relaunch which calls npm install to install+rebuild your new upstream dependences before it relaunches your node ... having it do a revert on error ... very doable yet obviously super vulnerable ... for dev only not production

Comment: If you found one of these answers useful you should accept it. It's helpful to future devs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is definitely possible, but probably inadvisable.

I found the npm module "npm-programmatic" which lets you npm install. Once you have that, all you need to do is wrap your require with a try catch so that you can handle when a require fails.

```
const npm = require('npm-programmatic')

let myPackage
try {
    myPackage = require('my-package')
} catch(err) {
    npm.install(['my-package']).then(function() {
        myPackage = require('my-package')
        console.log(myPackage)
    })
}
```

The biggest problem you're probably going to face here is that the script will need to be running with more than standard privileges. You will likely need to sudo run this script which is very inadvisable.

Answer (score 0):

No, I think that there is no way to accomplish your aim, and in fact, it is a "bad" idea, I think.

Under Node.js, we always use package.json to manage all dependencies, and when we want to deploy them, we only use to run

```
$npm install
```

it is very easy and effective, but based on your mind, we need write a new function instead of require function, for example, require2, and while we use it to load the module, it always check the module exists or not at first, it is not effective, I think.

Comment: Typically it would be a bad idea, but we're using private repos in a closed environment. It's just a comfortable way to maintain something for us.